# Within subscription event emitter?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to refresh my chart component after I entered some values into my input field. I am not sure how I can do it

**Here is my start.component.hmtl**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue"/>
<select  (change)="selectedItem($event)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

The data which I receive over ngMode directive I am passing to chart component like this:

```
  <app-chart [optionsIncome]="options"  [inputValue]="inputValue"></app-chart>
```

But my problem is after I entered the input field I need to re-render the chart.component template as well. With the dropdown field it is working fine. How can I do it with the ngModel directive which I passed to other component and subscribed over BehaviourSubject.

Here an example: 
  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjk2ru)

Comment: How do you re-render the chart when the `select` value changes?

Comment: In the start.component.ts 
  reload () {
    this.show = false;
    setTimeout(() => this.show = true);
  }

Comment: Your example is completely unrelated to the code in your question. If you need to know when the inputValue input changes inside app-chart, use ngOnChanges. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: So you call `reload` in `selectedItem()`? You can do the same with `<input ... (ngModelChange)="reload()">`.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your example can't work when change dropdown field, I guess you want to use the same logic after the input and dropdown value change, you can use ngModelChange function to pass your inputValue

```js
export class StartComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItem(data) {
    if (data) {
      this.data.push(data);
      this.reload();
    }
    ...
  }

  changeByInput(inputValue) {
    this.selectedItem(inputValue);
  }

}
```

```html
// start.component.html
<div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (ngModelChange)="changeByInput($event)" /></div>
```